# Minimum Spanning Tree of Subgraph

Tags: graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Suppose you have a graph `G` = (`V`, `E`). You can do whatever you want in terms of preprocessing on this graph `G` (within reasonable time and space constraints for a graph with a few thousands vertices, so you couldn't just store every possible answer for example).

Now suppose I select a subset `V'` of `V`. I want the MST over just these vertices `V'`. How do you do this quickly and efficiently?

Comment: What approaches have you thought of? Why have you rejected them? As far as I can see, it's a choice between creating a new graph `G' = (V', E')` or operating on `G` and simply ignoring vertices in `{V} - {V'}`.

Comment: In what you described, either way it sounds like you're rebuilding an MST from scratch. I considered starting from the MST of `G` and incrementally removing vertices, but this quickly becomes more costly than just starting over. Wondering if there's some other result you could cache that you could exploit at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me from your question that you were trying to re-use the MST of `G`. Are you given a specific subset `V'` or are you trying to find the subset that minimizes the cost, or maybe something else?

Comment: You can reuse anything you can compute beforehand (within reasonable space limitations). You get an arbitrary subset at runtime, and you need to find the MST of that subset.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve the problem. Their performance is dependent to different states of the problem.

1. Applying MST algorithms on sub-graph(solve from scratch).
2. Using dynamic algorithms to update tree after changes in the problem.
   There are two types of dynamic algorithms:
   I) Edge insertion and deletion**
   G. Ramalingam and T. Reps, “On the computational complexity of
   dynamic graph problems,” Theoret. Comput. Sci., vol. 158, no. 1, pp.
   233–277, 1996.
   II) Edge weight decreasing and increasing**
   D. Frigioni, A. Marchetti-Spaccamela, and U. Nanni, “Fully dynamic
   output bounded single source shortest path problem,” in ACM-SIAM
   Symp. Discrete Algorithms, 1996, pp. 212–221.
   “Fully dynamic algorithms for maintaining shortest paths trees,”
   J. Algorithms, vol. 34, pp. 251–281, 2000.
   You can use them directly or change them with respect to the problem and consider node insertion and deletion.

Comment: As I said above, neither are good options. In the first, you don't save any time. In the second, this quickly becomes even more costly than the first.

Comment: In the second approach, if removed nodes don't belong to MST, then the complexity is O(1). else if all nodes be in MST then the complexity is O(n*log (n)) which is equal to the first approach and the running time grows by a constant coefficient. In some case, it can improve the run time. First, a few removed nodes affect MST. Second, your network has a predictable changes and you can statistically update MST by running the second approach. You can refer to [Dynamic Algorithms for the Shortest Path Routing Problem: Learning Automata-Based Solutions].

Comment: I'm not sure how the removed nodes won't belong to an MST. An MST will span all the nodes, so by definition any node that you are going to removed will be in full MST.

Comment: The nodes should be removed in an incremental manner. At each step, one node should be processed and if it affects MST, the dynamic algorithms should be run.

Comment: Again, not sure we're talking about the same thing, because each node removal will certainly affect the MST by definition.

Comment: However, each node removal affects MST, but it may not change the other shortest paths. It means that the node does not lie in the other shortest paths. If you carefully read and implement the mentioned papers, you can find out the capabilities of dynamic shortest path algorithms.

Comment: As I previously said, this is not what I'm looking for, thanks for trying though.